# Return a collection of most frequent characters in a string

Tags: c#

My task was write a method that has input parameter - string  and this method must return a collection of symbols which are most frequently , for example:

- input: ааа bbb с
- ouput: а, b
- input:  ааа bb с
- ouput: a
- а, b, с
- - а b с

Here is my bad code:

```
 static void test(string s)
        {
            int[] cc = new int[255];
            char c;

            for (c = (char)0; c < 255; c++)
            {
                cc[c] = 0;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                cc[s[i]]++;
            }
            int cntMax = 0;


            for ( c =(char) 0; c < 255; c++)
            {
             if(cc[c] > cntMax)
                {
                    cntMax = cc[c];
                }
            }
            string L = "";
            if(cntMax >0 )
            {
                for ( c = (char)0; c < 255; c++)
                {
                    if(cc[c] == cntMax)
                    {
                        if(c > (char) 32)
                        {
                            L = L + c + " ";
                            Console.WriteLine(L);
                        }
                    }



                }
            }
        }
```

So  , I don't sure if understand  , I must return collection of symbols , how to do it? How can I change my code?? And also I have a question about input: if I input a b c , then my program count spaces instread of symbols , how to fix it? Sorry for my very bad code

Comment: _I must return collection of symbols , how to do it?_ This part of your question is off-topic because Code Review isn't about writing code for you. Another part about _if I input a b c , then my program count spaces instread of symbols , how to fix it?_ is off-topic either because your code seems to be broken. Code Review requires you to provide working code.

Comment: @t3chb0t okay I provide working code , I asked how can I refactor it with collection that's all

Comment: Not getting this for (c = (char)0; c < 255; c++)

Comment: At least format better before posting

Comment: As an aside, I would argue that the most frequent characters in the string "a, b, c" are "," and " ".  Not "a", "b" and "c".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter (depending if you are useing ascii or utf) with some if statements like:

```
if((charactervar!=32)&(characterval!=44)){
    //filter ascii character for blank/space 32 and comma 44
}
```

...

```
static void test(string s)
    {
        int[] cc = new int[255];
        char c;

        for (c = (char)0; c < 255; c++)
        {
            cc[c] = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
           if((s[i]!=(char)32)&(s[i]!=(char)44)){ //if you use a different encoding than ascii please replace the numbers with the appropriate numbers from the character table
              cc[s[i]]++;
           }
        }
        int cntMax = 0;


        for ( c = (char)0; c < 255; c++)
        {
         if(cc[c] > cntMax)
            {
                cntMax = cc[c];
            }
        }
        string L = "";
        if(cntMax >0 )
        {
            for ( c =(char) 0; c < 255; c++)
            {
                if(cc[c] == cntMax)
                {
                    if(c > 32) //and here
                    {
                        L = L + c + " ";
                    }
                }
            }
        Console.Write(L);
    }
```

You could also consider the use of regular expressions like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565934/regular-expression-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters
(I know it's java but the concept should be the same)

And I'm not an expert to ask for "pretty" code as I only focus to make it work :). But you could save some lines where you initialize your int array cc. I think there is a way to write that shorter.

Comment: it wrote collection of symbols in task , and u wrote me "   
Not getting this for (c = (char)0; c < 255; c++) " how to correctly do it??

Comment: That was not his comment and you did not answer the question.  Focus.

Comment: Then at the end he has if(c > (char) 32)

Comment: So you want to exclude all things like "space" or "newline". Sorry if I missunderstood your question.

Comment: @BenyBenz yes , my code workd for 1 and 2 cases , but you can see at 3 case and here it is my problem , how to ignore it , also u can see there coma

Comment: @M-Misha-M Can you please specify which characters you want to ignore. (Until now I know about space, comma)

Comment: @BenyBenz in my case it's just a coma and space , but where I have to paste your code in my code? Also can u please help me refactor for loop because I don't understand why guys wrote me about (char) in loop. Thanks

Comment: I think you shoudn't need the (char) conversion at all.

Comment: @BenyBenz okay thanks , but I get error without char  - cannot convert int to char

Comment: I don't know if this applies to c# sorry was just a guess... Plz give me some time to look it up...

Comment: Does it work with the char conversion? I mean that it filters " " and "," if you add the (char) conversion everywhere (in my if too).

Comment: @BenyBenz yes it works with char but something strange with output 1 line: a. 2 line: a b. 3 line: a b c :/ it all output in 3 lines together instread of 1 line with a b c . Do u know what's wrong?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char. Ok the char of c# is completely different than that of c, so if i got it right it has 16bit? It outputs it like a (newline) b(newline) c?

Comment: Maybe by use of Console.write()... Instead of Console.writeline()? It could be that writeline creates a new line for every character

Comment: @BenyBenz so I get a a b a b c :) omg

Comment: Because you change your string in each run :). After first run through the loop it has the value a, thr next run it has a b and the last one a b c... Possible solution: 1.Move the Console.write to the end of your code (at least out of the for loop) unfortunately I cant debug C# because I'm on my phone right now (no c# compiler available there)

Comment: @BenyBenz yes , it works thanks. But my code so bad isn't it?? Exactly with char ^/

Comment: I don't know why you are calling your code "bad", I think it isn't: It works and was in my opinion relativeley easy to understand. There would be possibilities to make it more efficient or to save some lines, but I thing it would decrease readability. My coding-style isn't better :). As long as if you look at your code like 1 month later and are able to explain it, i would not bother about " bad" or "good" code tol much. With every program/problem you solve your code will get "better" (to debug because you will learn what problem it is to understand your own code after some time) :)

Comment: @BenyBenz: comparing against character literals such as `' '` and `','` instead of 'magic values' would make your code easier to understand. Also, the `&` operator is normally only used for bitwise operations. It doesn't do short-circuiting, unlike the `&&` operator, so I wouldn't use it here.

Answer (score 1):

### Text and data structures

C# uses UTF-16 internally, so a `char` is actually 2 bytes long (and even then not all Unicode characters can be stored in a `char`). An array of 256 (a single byte can have 256, not 255, different values) is not sufficient. A `Dictionary<char, int>` would be more suitable here. For example, the following code is not limited to Latin characters, so feeding it some Cyrillic should work just fine:

```
var charCounts = new Dictionary<char, int>();
foreach (char c in s)
{
    if (!charCounts.ContainsKey(c))
        charCounts[c] = 1;
    else
        charCounts[c]++;
}
```

You said that you want to ignore space characters, but your code also ignores some control characters (but not all). You may want to use `char.GetUnicodeCategory` to determine which characters should be counted (there are several categories: various kinds of letters, digits, control characters and so on).

As for returning multiple characters, that's what arrays and lists are for. Instead of appending characters to a string, add them to a list and return that list when you're finished.

### Other comments

- Don't use 'magic values' (such as that 255 that's appearing several times). When you iterate an array, use its `Length` property: `for (int i = 0; i < cc.Length; i++)`.
- Using a `char` to index an array makes your code a little confusing to read. I don't see any advantages over using a 'standard' `int`.
- I would also not recommend reusing an indexing variable (`c`): it's easy to introduce bugs by forgetting to 'reset' its value.
- You don't need to initialize an array of ints with 0's: C# already does that for you (0 is the default value for `int`).
- Try using meaningful variable names: `text` or `input` instead of `s`, `charCounts` or even `characterCounts` instead of `cc`, and so on. It'll make your code easier to understand, and that's a good thing when you have to revisit code a few months later.
- The easiest way to get the maximum value from a collection is to use Linq's `Max` method: `cc.Max()`. There are also several other Linq methods that could make this method easier to write, such as `GroupBy`, `Where` and  `ToDictionary`.

Comment: Okay  , let's move next , I understand about Length in loop , explain please about using int instread of (char) that is present in my "for" loop

Comment: about dictionary , is it best way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799440/returning-most-frequent-characters-in-a-string (code of topic starter) ?

Comment: @M-Misha-M: the accepted answer to that question shows some improvements over the topic starter, but yeah, that's the general idea. As for what's 'best', that very much depends on requirements, available time, and so on. As for using `int` instead of `char`, it's about intent. When you want to look up the count of a certain character, it makes sense to cast a `char` to an `int` (index). But if you need to loop over the array, using a `char` as counter variable only makes things more confusing.

Comment: can u show me how to rewrite code without char?? How my loops looks like

Comment: I already did: `for (int i = 0; i < cc.Length; i++)` instead of `for ( c =(char) 0; c < 255; c++)`.

Comment: i changed my code here https://pastebin.com/FV620NXD now I get int number of characters and also I don't know where to put your part of code with dictionary

Comment: The dictionary is meant to replace your `cc` array - that's why I gave it the name `charCounts`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64212/discussion-between-m-misha-m-and-pieter-witvoet).